# Setup VPN access on a windows dedicated server for browsing

Tags: windows-server-2008, vpn, routing, rras

I have a dedicated windows server. I want to create a VPN to encrypt my traffic (browsing, IM, etc) as I browse on my laptop using public wifi networks.

What keywords should I be using to search Google? Are there any resources that help me do this? Most of the solutions are just to encrypt communication between the server to a machine. It does not act like an internet gateway, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default Windows VPN will use the default gateway provided by the RRAS server when connected to the VPN.  So all your web browsing, IM'ing etc, will be encrypted.

[image]
<sub>(source: [haacked.com](http://haacked.com/images/haacked_com/WindowsLiveWriter/RouteAroundTheDefaultGatewayOnTheRemoteN_ADA/Vpn-Settings%5B14%5D.png))</sub>